# Apportable -Is -fno-objc-arc supported

Tags: android, ios, automatic-ref-counting, compiler-flags, apportable

I have some files in my project which don't support ARC, hence the flag. Compiling for iOS works as intended, compiling with Apportable throws some errors (arc forbids explicit call for release). It seems like the flag is ignored. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: -fno-objc-arc is the proper stop for a file compiler flag

Comment: I don't quiet understand what you try to tell me with this. I have this flag entered under Build Phases. May it be interfering with -w, a flag I also have set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this flag is supported. our build system had an issue where these flags may not have been picked up, but I *think* this problem was fixed the SDK we shipped today. if you look at the Release.final json, you should see the flag in the flags list for that particular source file.

Comment: I'll try tommorrow. It's quiet late here in Berlin at the moment.